# How to allow WordPress updates to only one specific administrator?

Tags: wp-admin, users, updates, automatic-updates

I found a code to prevent WordPress update for certain user role:

```
add_action( 'init', function () {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
        add_filter( 'pre_site_transient_update_core', 'disable_updates' );     // Disable WordPress core updates
        add_filter( 'pre_site_transient_update_plugins', 'disable_updates' );  // Disable WordPress plugin updates
        add_filter( 'pre_site_transient_update_themes', 'disable_updates' );   // Disable WordPress theme updates
    }
} );
```

What about allowing to update for only one user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

We take this code and paste it to functions.php :

```
function createit_hide_upd_for_other_adm_users() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( 777 != $current_user->ID ) { //change the user ID
        add_filter( 'pre_site_transient_update_core', 'disable_updates' );
        add_filter( 'pre_site_transient_update_plugins', 'disable_updates' );
        add_filter( 'pre_site_transient_update_themes', 'disable_updates' );
    } else {
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'createit_hide_upd_for_other_adm_users' );
```

You just need to find the correct **WordPress user ID** and put it in place of 777, thats it!